# Add custom headers to sip response through asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am using the Asterisk PBX to relay sip requests and responses to and from devices. I would like to know if there is a way to add custom headers to my sip responses, similar to adding custom header fields through the use of SipAddHeader(). Or, if not, is there any way I can just reconfigure Asterisk to send the custom requests and responses I send to it straight to the target device, without asterisk duplicating some fields and recreating a new request or response. Thank you and have a great one.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way do that in CHAN_SIP without chan_sip.c rewrite(major rewrite, not much tracking here).

You can use kamailio or opensips as proxy and change any headers or packets using it.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it!